# java Apache POI 3.9 Eclipse (reading big xlsx files)

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache

I'm trying to read a series of excel files (.xlsx) but when the file have to many lines it seams the code wont work.. when the file is small its all ok. I'm trying to read from the second sheet of every file the first column starting from line 5. this is my code:

```
String FilePath ="C:\\xxx";
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] listOfFiles = new File(FilePath).listFiles();


    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile() && listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(listOfFiles[i].getName().length()-4).equals("xlsx")) {              

        int pos_data = 0;       
        String excelFilePath = "C:\\xxx\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName();
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));


        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
        java.util.Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            java.util.Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                if(pos_data > 4)
                    data.add(cell.getStringCellValue());

                pos_data++;

        }   

        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
      }
    }
```

I've done already some test and when the files are big, in the first iteration *fisrtSheet.getLastRowNum()* returns -1 and the value in *cell* returns the last value in the column.

i try to figure it out for myself but I've never used POI before so i ask you for an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **SXSSF** instead of **XSSF**. This should allow you to handle large excel files.
https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i need to read a large excel file not write. the writing part have no problem at all.